Why do some perturbative calculations in QFT have a closed form answer?
In a lecture on new theories of physics by Nina Arkani-Hamed (see 21:30 onwards: https://youtu.be/GL77oOnrPzY?t=1294) it was mentioned that for some calculations in QFT, the sum of all Feynman diagrams ultimately yields a closed form solution for an unknown reason.
I would like to ask if anyone can share some insight into which cases these may be and if the underlying reason is really unknown. Is there new physics to be found here?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHV_amplitudes

@PeterKravchuk Although my knowledge of physics limits my understanding of this, I think it answers my question.

I don't do high energy; here's some thought from condensed matters.
Interaction of two non-relativistic particles in the vacuum by $\delta$-function (pseudo)potential is a simple example.  Since there is no virtual pair creation, perturbation theory just yields repeated scatterings, which can be summed exactly as a geometric series, and you get the exact T-matrix.
In a sense, this is like expanding $\cos(x)$ in power series (perturbation series), take $d/dx$ term by term (explicit calculation of each term), and sum the resultant series to determined that $d\cos(x)/dx = -\sin(x)$ (resummation).
Under normal circumstances, complete resummation of perturbation theory is impossible.  (Why else would we want to expand the problem in the first place?)  But partial resummation is done all the time.  If you believe a certain class of infinitely many Feynman diagrams are particularly important for what you are studying, and you have a way to resum them, then you do it.  The literature for strongly correlated physics is chockful of this approach.
The result is only as good as your starting intuition, though.  You may discover non-perturbative phenomenon, or your "discovery" may be completely irrelevant.

Thank you for the answer
